# How do I create a 2D Circle out of squares (tiles)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, geometry, dynamically-generated

So basically what I'm trying to do is generate a circle completely out of square tiles in Unity and I am trying to think about the best way mathematically to generate it.

In the end, I want it to look something like:

https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTHh7I_BURo5qMI73YLZVG6PO4WeFtbT--QL_9qOJovpNaWemar

In this image, the tiles are more rectangular and not all sides are equal, but it gets the point across.

Does anyone know of any mathematical formulas or anything that could be helpful in doing this? I don't necessarily need straight answers (unless you have them :D), but anything to help me along would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't possible if you really want the tiles to be square and have no gaps or overlaps. The radial edges won't touch in that case.

Comment: Hmm. I may make the tiles ever so _slightly_ curved then.

Comment: You'll also have issues if you want to keep your squares the same size in consecutive rings.

Comment: How do you suggest I remedy that?

Comment: Either you can't have radial lines, or you need to make the tiles larger on each ring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the starting point (center) and start drawing your first square in the starting direction. Now turn the direction with the [Golden ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio): 1.618...

Keep turning this much for every consecutive square you are drawing, every time increasing the distance from the center a little bit.

Apparently sunflowers also grow following this pattern according to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kkGeOWYOFoA)!

Comment: Woops, typo! Thanks erbridge!